# Получения списка wifi android. _wifi.ScanResults пуст

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, wifi

Мне необходимо получить список доступных wifi сетей.
На теперешний момент есть такой код. Но в _wifi.ScanResults; не содержится ни одной сети.

`_wifi = (WifiManager) _context.GetSystemService(Context.WifiService);
            _wifi.StartScan();
            IList<ScanResult> wifiNetworks = _wifi.ScanResults;`

Answer (score 0):

Сканирование не синхронное, соответственно результаты сканирования будут доступны не сразу. Вам надо зарегистрировать BroadcastReceiver с фильтром `WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION`, и при оповещении уже 
брать ScanResults.